# getting a Java program to write to CentOS 7 terminal

Tags: java, linux, terminal, centos

From the CentOS 7 terminal, I can run the java program below by typing `javac /path/to/TestJDBC.java`.  But the problem is that the SYSO commands in the program have no place to go when called from the terminal.  **How can I change the Java code below so that the SYSO commands get printed to the terminal instead?**  I know that I could use a FileOutputStream() and then nano the created file name, but I would like to avoid creating a bunch of unnecessary test files.

```
package somepackage;
//STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;

public class TestJDBC {
 // JDBC driver name and database URL
 static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
 static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somedb?autoReconnect=true";

 //  Database credentials
 static final String USER = "usrname";
 static final String PASS = "pword";

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Connection conn = null;
 Statement stmt = null;
 try{
    //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    //STEP 3: Open a connection
    System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

    //STEP 4: Execute a query
    System.out.println("Creating statement...");
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String sql;
    sql = "SELECT id, name FROM peeps";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
    while(rs.next()){
       //Retrieve by column name
       int id  = rs.getInt("id");
       String name = rs.getString("name");

       //Display values
       System.out.print("ID: " + id);
       System.out.println(", name: " + name);
    }
    //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
 }catch(SQLException se){
    //Handle errors for JDBC
    se.printStackTrace();
 }catch(Exception e){
    //Handle errors for Class.forName
    e.printStackTrace();
 }finally{
    //finally block used to close resources
    try{
       if(stmt!=null)
          stmt.close();
    }catch(SQLException se2){
    }// nothing we can do
    try{
       if(conn!=null)
          conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException se){
       se.printStackTrace();
    }//end finally try
 }//end try
 System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}//end main
}//end FirstExample
```

**EDIT**

I tried @Immibis's method, and the program starts to run by throws a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` error at the line of code that says `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`.  I cannot really evaluate the ability of the program to print to the terminal until errors like this are resolved.  **How can I resolve this and similar errors in the simple code above?**

Comment: `javac /path/to/TestJDBC.java` does *not* run the program. It compiles the program.

Comment: @immibis `javac /path/to/TestJDBC.java` is the first thing I have tried that returns without throwing an error.  Are you willing to suggest a complete solution, if you think that my posting only defines part of the problem?

Comment: @immibis After successfully typing `javac /path/to/TestJDBC.java` without any errors being returned, subsequently typing `java TestJDBC` results in `error: Class names, 'TestJDBC', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested 1 error`.  Can you please provide correct syntax for running the program, if you think I have not run it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javac` is the *compiler*. You are compiling your program, but not running it.

Since your package is `somepackage`, you should have a folder `somepackage` containing `TestJDBC.java`. `cd` to that folder, then run:

```
javac somepackage/TestJDBC.java
java somepackage.TestJDBC
```

(It is usually a good idea to make your source folders follow your package structure)

Comment: @CodeMed You could just take my word for it that `System.out.println` will print to the terminal (but currently those statements never get executed, because your program crashes first), or you could fix the problems with your code so that it works, and then see whether it prints to the terminal.

Comment: I am fixing the problems.  I got it to print to the terminal, so thank you and +1.  Are you willing to help me with the remaining aspect of the problem?  Here is the link: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184613/centos-7-not-allowing-internal-database-connections-why-not?